# Why is my BMI averaging code not working correctly?

Tags: c#

I am trying to calculate the average BMI of a number of people. When I run this code, the average BMI goes down every time I click the calculate button. Why?

```
float feet;
float inches;
float height;
float weight;
float bmi;
float averagebmi;

try
{
    //Get user input.
    feet = float.Parse(txtFeet.Text);
    inches = float.Parse(txtInches.Text);
    weight = float.Parse(txtWeight.Text);

    //Calculations.
    inches += feet * 12;
    height = inches * (float)0.0254;
    weight = weight * (float)0.453592;
    bmi = weight / (height * height);

    //Manager Calculations.
    totalPeople += 1;
    bmi += 1;
    averagebmi = bmi / totalPeople;
```

Comment: Are you doing this in a loop? If you don't reset the values of your variables back to zero before re-using them then their values will accumulate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The average BMI should be the total BMI divided by the total people.

You need to add:

```
float totalbmi;
```

Then the manager calculations should be:

```
//Manager Calculations.
totalPeople += 1;
totalbmi += bmi;
averagebmi = totalbmi / totalPeople;
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! Can't believe I had that code before but I deleted it cause I thought that it was wrong.